# BigInt calculator spitting out slightly wrong results

Tags: c++, arrays, math, element

So for my assignment I have to create a calculator that works with big integers up to 256 characters in length. The current part of the assignment I'm up to is getting it work with multiplication of larger numbers. DIGITS is the limit of digits per Bigint class, currently set to 20 for debug sake, but will go up to 256

When doing a calculation like 25 * 137, I get the answer 3285 when it should be 3425. When I look through the couts that I put in place for debug, the first iteration of the i loop works perfectly and adds 685 to sum which is 5 * 137, so that works perfect. However when it gets to the bit where it's having to do the second iteration of the i loop where it is 20 * 137, it's getting the answer wrong and I cannot work out why. I have an inkling that it's something to do with the carry being two digits (14), but I still can't really work out how I can fix it.

The main implementation that obviously has something wrong with it is in the * operator of the bigint class. I know it's not to do with the << or >> operators as they work perfectly for addition and subtraction.

Full code of the bigint class is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Bigint.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

Bigint::Bigint()
{
    for (int i = DIGITS-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        digits_[i] = 0;
    }
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Bigint& n)
{

    string s = "";
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(n.digits_[i] > 0) {
            found = true;
        }
        if(n.digits_[i] != 0 || found == true) {
            s += char(n.digits_[i] + '0');
        }
    }
    if (s == "") {
        s = "0";
    }
    return out << s;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, Bigint& n)
{
    // Extracts full-length number (does not work for any other length).
    // All characters are assumed to be valid digits.
    //
    string s;
    if (in >> s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i) {
            n.digits_[i] = i < s.length() ? s[s.length() - 1 - i] - '0' : 0;
        }
    }
    return in;
}

Bigint operator+ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    Bigint ret;
    int cur_carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i) {
        int n1_digit = n1.get(i);
        int n2_digit = n2.get(i);
        if(n1_digit < 0 || n1_digit > 9) {
            n1_digit = 0;
        }
        if(n2_digit < 0 || n2_digit > 9) {
            n2_digit = 0;
        }
        //printf("n1 : %d\n", n1_digit);
        //printf("n2 : %d\n", n2_digit);
        int sum = n1_digit + n2_digit + cur_carry;
        //cout << "sum : " << sum << endl;
        cur_carry = Bigint::getCarry(sum);
        //cout << "new carry : " << cur_carry << endl;
        ret.set(i, Bigint::getDigitValue(sum));
        //cout << "Set : " << i << "," << Bigint::getDigitValue(sum) << endl;
    }
    return ret;
}

Bigint operator* (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    Bigint ret;
    //int borrowed = 0;
    Bigint sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS ; i++){
        int n1_digit = n1.get(i);
        //cout << "n2: " << n2_digit << endl;
        Bigint temp;

        if(n1_digit < 0 || n1_digit > 9) {
            n1_digit = 0;
        }

        int carry = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS ; j++){
            int val = n1_digit * (pow(10, i)) * n2.get(j);
            cout << "n1: " << n1_digit << endl;
            cout << "n2: " << n2.get(j) << endl;

            if(carry != 0){
                temp.set(j, (Bigint::getDigitValue(val)) + carry);
                cout << "Carry was " << carry << ", now set 0" << endl;
                cout << "value to set: " << (Bigint::getDigitValue(val)) + carry << endl;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else if(carry == 0){
                temp.set(j, Bigint::getDigitValue(val));
                cout << "value to set: " << (Bigint::getDigitValue(val))<< endl;
            }

            carry = (Bigint::getCarry(val) + carry);
            cout << "carry: " << carry << endl;
        }
        cout << "Sum before adding temp: " << sum << endl;
        sum = sum + temp;
        cout << "Sum after adding temp: " << sum << endl;


    }

    ret = sum;
    return ret; // Only correct when n2 equals 1.
}

int Bigint::get(int pos) const {
    //Return address of digit for reading
    int ret = digits_[pos];
    return ret;
}

void Bigint::set(int pos, int val) {
    this->digits_[pos] = val;
}

int Bigint::getCarry(int val) {
    //Integer division, always floors
    return val/10;
}

int Bigint::getDigitValue(int val) {
    return val % 10;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef BIGINT_H_
#define BIGINT_H_

#define DIGITS 20

class Bigint
{
  public:

    /**
     * Creates a Bigint initialised to 0.
     */
    Bigint();

    /**
     * Inserts n into stream or extracts n from stream.
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Bigint& n);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Bigint& n);

    /**
     * Returns the sum, difference, product, or quotient of n1 and n2.
     */
    friend Bigint operator* (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);
    friend Bigint operator+ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);

    int get(int pos) const;
    void set(int pos, int val);

    static int getCarry(int val);
    static int getDigitValue(int val);

  private:
    int digits_[DIGITS];
};

#endif // BIGINT_H_
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bigint.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Bigint n1, n2;
    char op;

    while (cin >> n1 >> op >> n2) {
        switch (op) {
        case '+' :
            cout << n1 + n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '*' :
            cout << n1 * n2 << endl;
            break;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, apologies, I have reduced the amount of code as much as possible to just include the issue

Comment: may I interest you in some unit testing?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, statement by statement, in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values? I also recommend that you simplify your expressions so it's easier to see the immediate results. For example `int val = n1_digit * (pow(10, i)) * n2.get(j)` could be split into `int t1 = pow(10, i);`int t2 = n1_digit * t1; int t3 = n2.get(j); int val = t2 * t3;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not in a debugger but, if you were to run that code, there's a bunch of cout statements that show each step of the process and it seems to be an issue with carrying double digits, for instance when 20 gets multiplied by 7 it is 140 so it has to carry 14 and set 0. Other than that everything else works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential problems

```cpp
        for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS ; j++){
            int val = n1_digit * (pow(10, i)) * n2.get(j); // val % 10 == 0 for i > 0
            // You should also be adding the carry to val
            cout << "n1: " << n1_digit << endl;
            cout << "n2: " << n2.get(j) << endl;

            if(carry != 0){
                temp.set(j, (Bigint::getDigitValue(val)) + carry);
                // This can set temp[j] to values above 9 depending on the carry
                cout << "Carry was " << carry << ", now set 0" << endl;
                cout << "value to set: " << (Bigint::getDigitValue(val)) + carry << endl;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else if(carry == 0){
                temp.set(j, Bigint::getDigitValue(val));
                cout << "value to set: " << (Bigint::getDigitValue(val))<< endl;
            }

            carry = (Bigint::getCarry(val) + carry);
            cout << "carry: " << carry << endl;
        }
```

Because you multiply by a power of 10, getDigitValue and getCarry aren't acting the way you expect them to. It might be better to shift the index for temp.set up by i instead of multiplying by pow(10, i).

I would also recommend cleaning up the cases. Both the if and the else if are actually doing the same work in this case, and resetting the carry doesn't do anything. So this would have the exact same behavior:

```cpp
        for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS ; j++){
            int val = n1_digit * (pow(10, i)) * n2.get(j);

            temp.set(j, (Bigint::getDigitValue(val)) + carry);
            // If the carry is 0, the addition doesn't do anything
            // You don't need to reset the carry to 0, since it's assigned here anyway
            carry = (Bigint::getCarry(val) + carry);
        }
```

Without the cases and without the print statements, it's much easier to read, but here the use of methods (getCarry and getDigitValue) still makes it hard to see the problem by moving the relevant operations to the bottom of the class. Making the changes gives:

```cpp
        for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS ; j++){
            int val = n1_digit * n2.get(j) + carry;

            temp.set(i + j, Bigint::getDigitValue(val));
            carry = Bigint::getCarry(val);
            // The carry just gets added to the value at the beginning
            // Everything else just works that way
        }
```

You also need to change the get and set functions so that they don't work out of bounds:

```cpp
int Bigint::get(int pos) const {
    //Return address of digit for reading
    if (pos >= DIGITS)
        return 0;
    int ret = digits_[pos];
    return ret;
}

void Bigint::set(int pos, int val) {
    if (pos >= DIGITS)
        return ;
    this->digits_[pos] = val;
}
```

With this code, I get 3425 for 25 * 137.

Comment: thankyou, this is very helpful, however simply turning it in to ` temp.set(j + i, Bigint::getDigitValue(val)); ` doesn't work. I can see your mindset, but I can't see why it wouldn't work, potentially the way the array is filled is the other way? The extra zero(s) needs to come before the initial value is put in to the array

Comment: @Cloppy it seems like it was probably because of out-of-bounds memory accesses by your get and set functions, adding a bounds check to each got the correct result for your test case

Answer (score 0):

you should not use this line`int val = n1_digit * (pow(10, i)) * n2.get(j);`

because it will give integer overflow since you are working with bigintger
instead use the digits in the multiplier and add zeros behind the result.

the number of zeros to add will depend on the position of the multiplier digit which you can find the variable i from this loop `for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS ; i++)` in the overloaded * function

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However I am having difficulty inserting zero's before the existing digits in the array as they must come BEFORE the existing elements

Comment: what if you inserted the zeros first?